# Will EVERY single sin you have ever committed be forgiven if you fasted for all of Ramadan?

Tags: hadith, sin, ramadan, forgiveness

I am talking about major and minor sins. I heard in a hadith where if someone fasts for all of Ramadan hoping for its rewards all of his sins will wash away like the foam of the sea. Please answer because I really want to be a good Muslim and not even be in hell for a single second.

Answer (score -1):

Al-Imran 3:31

> Say, “If you love God, then follow me, and God will love you, and will
> forgive you your sins.” God is Forgiving and Merciful.

An-Nisa 4:137

> Those who believe, then disbelieve, then believe, then disbelieve,
> then increase in disbelief, God will not forgive them, nor will He
> guide them to a way.

If you love and follow God, He will forgive you your sins.

If you sin, saying, I will repent next Ramadan, then sin again, repent next Ramadan, ..  God will not forgive.

Of course, minor sin, something done unintentionally, may always occur. God will forgive those who follow Him and His Word and do good.

It is not for fasting during Ramadan that God will forgive but that we ask Him to forgive, believe in Him and His message in truth and follow His Will. Respecting Ramadan is part of His commandments. He also tells us many times to do good and forgive those who are in due to us.

Comment: Misses the point. "Whoever fasted the month of Ramadan out of sincere Faith (i.e. belief) and hoping for a reward from Allah, then all his past sins will be forgiven" (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2014)

Comment: @Qaaf What is the difference? Hoping for forgiveness or asking for forgiveness is the same before God. He knows our hearts, whether we pronounce it or not. "out of sincere faith" = "in true deen", includes true regret.